# NameError showing up but I don't understand why

Tags: python, nameerror

I have some code written for a school project but it shows errors on all of the cost parts of my code

```
fullname = input("whats your name?")
print("hello",fullname,)
print("room 1")
width=input("how wide is the room?")
length=input("how long is the room?")
area = float(length)*float(width)
print("the total area is",area,)

q = input("do you want another room?")
if q == "yes":
   print("room 2 ")
   widtha=input("how wide is the room?")
   lengtha=input("how long is the room?")
   areaa = float(lengtha) * float(widtha)
   print("the total area is",areaa,".")
else:
   flooring=input("do you want to have wood flooring(10) or tiled flooring(15)")
   if flooring == "wood":
      costaa = float(area)+ float(areaa)*10
      print("total cost is ",costaa,)
   if flooring == "tiled":
      costab = float(area)+ float(areaa)*15
      print("total cost is £",costab,)
```

It will show `NameError:costab` or `NameError:costaa` as not defined depending which I select.

Comment: areaa variable is not defined in else statement. it's define in if statement which may not be executed.I don't know if you understand

Comment: A Python error message usually shows the line where the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is simple.
When the computer says: Do you want another room? and you say no, you are not defining the value of areaa at all. Therefore, the areaa does not exist because you didn't specify it. I've made some changed to your code to make it working, hope it help!

```
fullname = input("Whats Your Name?")
print("Hello", fullname)
print("\nRoom 1")

width = input("How wide is the room?")
length = input("How long is the room?")

area = float(length) * float(width)
print("The Total Area is", area)

q = input("\nDo you want Another Room? (y/n)")

if q == "y":
    print("\nRoom 2")
    width2 = input("How wide is the room?")
    length2 = input("How long is the room?")
    area2 = float(length2) * float(width2)
    print("The Total Area is", area2,".")

    flooring=input("\nDo you want to have Wood Flooring(10) or Tiled Flooring(15)? (wood/tiled)")
    if flooring == 'wood':
        cost = area + area2 * 10
        print("Total Cost is ",cost)
    if flooring == 'tiled':
        cost2 = area + area2 * 15
        print("Total Cost is ",cost2)

else:
    flooring=input("\nDo you want to have Wood Flooring(10) or Tiled Flooring(15)? (wood/tiled)")
    if flooring == 'wood':
        cost = area * 10
        print("Total Cost is ",cost)
    if flooring == 'tiled':
        cost2 = area * 15
        print("Total Cost is ",cost2)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tested your code and runs ok on my pc. Maybe it's your configurations.

For python 2

input_variable = raw_input("Enter your name: ")

If you are using **Python 3.x**, raw_input has been renamed to **input**